# Melting multiple columns into one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, pandas-melt

I have been trying to melt this columns

```
d = {'key': [1,2,3,4,5], 'a': ['None','a', 'None','None','None'], 'b': ['None','None','b','None','None'],'c':['None','None','None','c','c']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I need to look like this

| key | letter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | None |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | c |
| 5 | c |

I tried:

```
df = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['key'], var_name = 'letters')
```

but i got:

| key | letters | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | None |
| 2 | a | a |
| 3 | a | None |
| 4 | a | None |
| 5 | a | None |
| 1 | b | None |
| 2 | b | None |
| 3 | b | b |
| 4 | b | None |
| 5 | b | None |
| 1 | c | None |
| 2 | c | None |
| 3 | c | None |
| 4 | c | c |
| 5 | c | c |

Answer (score 2):

If need get first non `None` value per rows after `key` column use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with replace possible `None` strings with back filling missing values and selected first column by position, last use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df.set_index('key')
        .replace('None', np.nan)
        .bfill(axis=1)
        .iloc[:, 0]
        .reset_index(name='letter')))
print (df)
   key letter
0    1    NaN
1    2      a
2    3      b
3    4      c
4    5      c
```

If possible multiple non `None` value per rows use:

```
d = {'key': [1,2,3,4,5], 
     'a': ['None','a', 'None','None','None'], 
     'b': ['None','b','b','None','None'],
     'c':['None','None','None','c','c']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df = (df[['key']].join(df.set_index('key')
        .replace('None', np.nan)
        .stack()
        .groupby(level=0)
        .agg(','.join)
        .rename('letter'), on='key'))
print (df)
   key letter
0    1    NaN
1    2    a,b
2    3      b
3    4      c
4    5      c
```

Or:

```
df = (df.set_index('key')
        .replace('None', np.nan)
        .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
        .replace('', np.nan)
        .reset_index(name='letter'))

print (df)
   key letter
0    1    NaN
1    2    a,b
2    3      b
3    4      c
4    5      c
```

Comment: Thank alot.  I'll like to know though, why did you not use melt function for this